# IE8 append on $(document).ready()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I'm aware there are similar questions to this but have looked at several and none have provided and actual solution.

I have a function that populates a table with row when the page loads if there are items to fill it with. This works fine in all browsers except IE8. If you refresh the page then the works as it should, however in IE8 if you simply navigate to the page the table is unchanged. I have put break points in the js in Developer Tools and the function was called and reached the end without error and when I examined the objects the table did contain the rows it was supposed to as far as the object was concerned but rows were not rendered in the actual table on the page.

Here is the code at the bottom of the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        addToTicketTable('12345');
    });
</script>
```

Any thoughts?

### Edit

Yes I am using tbody and function works fine when called by selecting a seat on the page or refreshing the page. It's only when navigating to the page that it doesn't work correctly.

As requested here is the code for the addToTicketTable function.

```
function addToTicketTable(seatId) {
var zone = $("#ddlSections").val();
var sectText = $("#ddlSections option:selected").text();
var sectName = sectText.split(":")[0]
var sect = sectText.split(" ")[0];
if (sectText.toLowerCase().indexOf(" box") >= 0) {
    sect += " " + sectText.split(" ")[1];
}
var seat = "Best Available";
var priceType = -1;
var seatInfo = "";

if ($(".dvSeat").length > 0) {
    var arrInfo = document.getElementById(seatId).getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value.split(",");

    priceType = arrInfo[4];
    sect = arrInfo[3];
    if ($("#" + seatId).attr("class").indexOf(" box") >= 0) {
        sect += " box";
    }
    seat = arrInfo[0] + arrInfo[1];
    if ($("#" + seatId).attr("class").indexOf("restrictedView") > -1) {
        seatInfo = "Restricted View";
    }
    if ($("#" + seatId).attr("class").indexOf("standingSeat") > -1) {
        seatInfo = "Standing Ticket";
    }
    if ($("#" + seatId).attr("class").indexOf("wheelchair") > -1) {
        seatInfo = "Wheel Chair Space";
    }
    if ($("#" + seatId).attr("class").indexOf("behindConductor") > -1) {
        seatInfo = "Behind Conductor";
    }
    if ($("#" + seatId).attr("class").indexOf("noSurtitles") > -1) {
        seatInfo = "Surtitles not visible";
    }
    if ($("#" + seatId).attr("class").indexOf("restrictedLegRoom") > -1) {
        seatInfo = "Restricted Leg Room";
    }
    zone = arrInfo[2];
}
var tdSect = document.createElement("td");
tdSect.innerHTML = sectName;

var tdSeat = document.createElement("td");
tdSeat.innerHTML = seat;
if (seatInfo.length > 0) {
    tdSeat.innerHTML += " (" + seatInfo + ")";
}
var hdSeat = document.createElement("input");
hdSeat.id = "tblHd" + seatId;
hdSeat.className = "seatHD";
hdSeat.type = "hidden";
hdSeat.value = seatId;
$(tdSeat).append(hdSeat);

var tdTicket = document.createElement("td");
var ddl = document.createElement("select");
ddl.id = "ddlTicket" + seatId;
ddl.className = "ddlTicket";

var ddlStr = "";
if (document.getElementById("ddl" + zone) != null) {
    ddlStr = "ddl" + zone;
} else {
    ddlStr = "ddl" + sect.split(":")[0];
    if (ddlStr.indexOf(" ") > -1) {
        ddlStr = ddlStr.split(" ")[0];
    }
}
$("#" + ddlStr + " option").each(function () {
    var arrVal = this.value.split(',');
    if (arrVal[0] == zone) {
        var selected = false;
        if (priceType != null) {
            if (this.value.split(',')[1] == priceType) {
                selected = true;
            }
        }
        if (selected) {
            $(ddl).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", this.value).text(this.text).attr("selected", "true"));
        } else {
            $(ddl).append($("<option></option>").attr("value", this.value).text(this.text));
        }
    }
});
$(ddl).change(function () {
    $("#lblPrice" + seatId).html($(this).val().split(',')[2]);
    updateSeatInfo();
});
$(tdTicket).append(ddl);

var tdPrice = document.createElement("td");
var lblPrice = document.createElement("span");
lblPrice.id = "lblPrice" + seatId;
$(tdPrice).append(lblPrice);

var tdRemove = document.createElement("td");
var btnRemove = document.createElement("span");
btnRemove.className = "btnRem";
$(btnRemove).click(function () {
    remSeat(seatId);
});
$(tdRemove).append(btnRemove);

var tr = document.createElement("tr");
tr.id = "tr" + seatId;

$(tr).append(tdSect);
$(tr).append(tdSeat);
$(tr).append(tdTicket);
$(tr).append(tdPrice);
$(tr).append(tdRemove);

$("#tblSeats tbody").append(tr);
$("#lblPrice" + seatId).html($(ddl).val().split(',')[2]);
}
```

Comment: Can you post the `addToTicketTable` code.

Comment: What version of JQuery are you using? You need to make sure you are using the 1.X branch to support IE8.

Comment: jquery 1.8.2. I avoid 2+ for exactly that reason

Comment: Caching problem maybe?

Comment: More than likely, you're trying to append a `<tr>` to a `<table>` element - this does not work in IE8.  You can only append rows to a `<tbody>` element - make sure your table structure is correct including your `<thead>` and `<tbody>` elements instead of allowing the browser to dynamically produce these for you.  I would be able to provide more detail if I saw the code for `addToTicketTable()`

Comment: Since I'm not sure what your page completely looks like - give this a shot:  instead of `$(document).ready()` try using `$(window).load()`.  It almost seems to me like `.ready()` is firing too early or your code is dependent upon something else that isn't fully loaded when `$(document).ready()` fires.  Give it a try and let me know what happens.

Comment: no joy with $(window).load() :(

Answer (score 0):

So I'm speculating a little here since enough code wasn't provided to fully determine the problem, so I'll share my experience with appending rows in IE8.

More than likely, you have a simple table structure like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Stuff</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and your script is something like this:

```
<script>
    $("table").append("<tr><td>More Stuff</td></tr>");
</script>
```

Well, IE8 doesn't allow you to append directly to a `<table>` element.  Instead, it requires that you set up the table structure correctly and append to a `<tbody>` element instead.  Like so:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Header</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Stuff</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and your jQuery would have to change to reflect the append to the `<tbody>` element:

```
<script>
    $("tbody").append("<tr><td>More Stuff</td></tr>");
</script>
```